# error with array and object in IDL corba

Tags: java, arrays, object, corba, idl

I got a problem with array and object in IDL corba
This is my code:

```
    interface ISinhVien
{
    SinhVien[] DocFile(in String filename);
    void GhiFile(in SinhVien[] sv,in String filename);
};
```

And error when I compile it:

```
CORBA_SinhVien>idlj -fall SinhVienIDL.idl
SinhVienIDL.idl (line 3):  SinhVien is an undeclared type.
        SinhVien[] DocFile(in String filename);
         ^
SinhVienIDL.idl (line 3):  Expected `<identifier>'; encountered `['.
        SinhVien[] DocFile(in String filename);
         ^
SinhVienIDL.idl (line 3):  WARNING: Identifier `String' collides with a keyword;
 use an escaped identifier to ensure future compatibility.
        SinhVien[] DocFile(in String filename);
                       ^
SinhVienIDL.idl (line 4):  SinhVien is an undeclared type.
        void GhiFile(in SinhVien[] sv,in String filename);
                         ^
SinhVienIDL.idl (line 4):  Expected `<identifier>'; encountered `['.
        void GhiFile(in SinhVien[] sv,in String filename);
                         ^
SinhVienIDL.idl (line 4):  WARNING: Identifier `String' collides with a keyword;
 use an escaped identifier to ensure future compatibility.
        void GhiFile(in SinhVien[] sv,in String filename);
```

Somebody help me, please !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The [CORBA language specification](https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDsQFjAC&url=http://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?formal/08-01-04.pdf&ei=UZZ2UbnJGIHRhAfYp4DoBA&usg=AFQjCNFtXyZcuskjs3-SW4TnKWeZjizzDA&sig2=uQZIi7ebDxFRVSpfmmUL6A&bvm=bv.45512109,d.ZG4) does not allow the arrays of any type to be returned unless they are first *typedefed*.

You have 2 options available here - fixed arrays or `sequences` - the latter is more flexible, allowing for the array size to be set by the implementing code.

```
interface SinhVien {
  boolean someOperation(in long id);
  // more operations
};

typedef sequence<SinhVien> sinhviens;


interface ISinhVien
{
    sinhviens docFile(in string filename);
    void ghiFile(in sinhviens sv, in string filename);
};
```

Aside: Be careful not to mix Java syntax with IDL syntax: `string` appears as all *lowercase*.

Comment: I edit code follow your help!
this my code is edited:

    typedef sequence<SinhVien> sinhviens;
    interface ISinhVien
    {
     sinhviens DocFile(in string filename);
     void GhiFile(in sinhviens sv,in string filename);
    }

but got error :

    SinhVienIDL.idl (line 1):  SinhVien is an undeclared type.
    typedef sequence<SinhVien> sinhviens;

help me,please!!

Comment: As the error says you need to define the type `SinhVien`. This can either be an `interface` or a `struct`. You can do this in the same IDL file or using a `#include` directive

Comment: you can explain detail for me?
I am new beginning

Comment: As already stated, you need to define the `SinhVien` type before it can be used. Read this [tutorial](http://documentation.progress.com/output/Iona/orbix/gen3/33/html/orbix33java_pguide/IDL.html)